# C# send Mysql Variable to another form

Tags: c#, mysql, variables, send

I have a problem when I try send MYSQL variable to Form2 like

```
  MySqlConnection open = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User=root;Password=123456789;database=on-line;pooling='true'; Max Pool Size = 100000");
        open.Open();


        MySqlCommand checker = new MySqlCommand("Select * From users where Mail = '" + TextMail.text.ToString() + "' ", open);
        MySqlDataReader MysqlReader = checker.ExecuteReader();


        if (MysqlReader.Read())
        {
            name = MysqlReader["Name"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {


        }

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.textbox1.text = name;
```

FORM 2

```
 string get = textbox1.text;
        MySqlConnection open = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;User=root;Password=123456789;database=on-line;pooling='true'; Max Pool Size = 100000");
        open.Open();


        MySqlCommand checker = new MySqlCommand("Select * From users where Mail = '" + get.ToString() + "' ", open);
        MySqlDataReader MysqlReader = checker.ExecuteReader();


        if (MysqlReader.Read())
        {
        }
        else
        {


        }
```

I am trying connect to my database but its not working... Have we any solution like sessions on .NET

Comment: "_It's not working..._" What is not working?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working" ? Do you get an error message ? If so, please post it. Reffer to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for best practices on posting questions.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `MySQL variable` outside the database itself. Perhaps you mean that you can't read something from the database? That could be because the code is critically flawed. If the textbox contains even a single quote you get a SQL injection vulnerability. Imagine what will happen if a user enters `'; delete from users#`

Comment: What is the value you got in the `name' variable

Comment: Find a tutorial on ADO.NET to understand how to query the database. Don't try code at random. Write *parameterized* queries to avoid SQL injections and conversion problems. Try a micro ORM like Dapper or a full ORM like Entity Framework to have them create correct queries for you. *Don't* create queries by concatenating strings. Even if you try to "sanitize" you'll still be vulnerable

Comment: @Wndrr I mean is when I try to connect database on Form2 within Name , it's not working.

Comment: @Ivar I changed my question can you look again.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I can not connect to the database on Form2

Comment: Where is the problem? Is there a MySQL connection issue? Or is it an issue in transmitting data across forms?

Comment: Place some breakpoints... Is the `get` variable being filled when you need it? Is the connection open when you called the Read method on the second form?

Comment: @EricWu no read method is not working because my get variable is empty